# How do I categorize a list of user inputs into different orders?

Tags: java

I am supposed to make a program that asks users for a list of input. Then, from that list, my program is supposed to pick out the third answer and then print it out. It sounds really simple, but how do I assign numbers to each of the user inputs? Do I even do that? I am a beginner, and thank you so much for your help!

This is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyProgram
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("What do you appreciate in your life or school?");
            String ans = scan.nextLine();
            if(ans.equals(""))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("You said \"" + input3 + "\" as your third answer.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to assign any String to any number. You just need an int counter variable that you increment within the loop, and then when it hits the right number, store the String that was inputted into a String variable (declared before the loop). Then print it after the loop.

Comment: But the question seems to have little to do with its title - I see no "categorizing into different orders".

Answer (score 0):

You can strore the third input in a variable you initialized bevor the loop.
if there is no third input it prints: ""

```
import java.util.*;


public class MyProgram
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int index = 0;
        String input3 = "";
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("What do you appreciate in your life or school?");
            String ans = scan.nextLine();
            if (index == 2) {
                input3 = ans;
            }

            if(ans.equals("")){
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }
        System.out.println("You said \"" + input3 + "\" as your third answer.");
    }
}
```